# Can $\cos(2x)+8\cos(4x)$ be simplified into $0.5A(\cos(a+b) + \cos(a-b))$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I know that there isn't a direct transformation, however can it be done using other identities?
I have tried the double angle formulas but ultimately they don't really provide me help as it introduces more functions.

EDIT: Im trying to eventually make it into Acos(a)cos(b)
can this be done?

Comment: Why don't you check the range of LHS and RHS?

Comment: @Shashwat1337 yes youre right, the ranges are different. However, I was hoping to eventually try to get it into the form Acos(a)cos(b), can this be done?

Comment: I'm not sure you can if you approach simply by product formulae since its form is lost on applying such an operation once. However, I may lack knowledge about advanced methods so I can't be sure about by claim.

Answer (score 1):

No. Your purported right hand side has magnitude at most 2, but your left hand side ranges from -9 to 9.

Comment: It's the right idea, but the magnitude of the LHS ranges from $-\frac{513}{64}$ to $9$, not from $-9$ to $9$.

Comment: I've made an edit clarifying where it was going to. Can it be done then?

Answer (score 0):

On the left hand side, using the formula $$\cos A + \cos B = 2 \left(\cos \frac {(A+B)}{2}\cos \frac{(A-B)}{2}\right)$$ we have $$2 \cos 3x \cos x + 7 \cos 4x$$

On the right hand side we have $$\frac {1}{2}A (\cos (A + B)+\cos (A-B))$$ which reduces to $$A \cos A \cos B$$

Note that we have the extra term $7 \cos 4x$ on the LHS.  That alone contradicts the form $A \cos A \cos B$, and even if we had that term vanish (also impossible; check by letting $x=0$), $A$ would either have to be $2x$ or $3x$.

Hence it is impossible to transform the LHS to the RHS.